# disable sorting in lineChart series in Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, charts

using Primefaces 5.0.4:
consider the below plots:

```
series4.set(6.63,3000);
series4.set(6.72,2997.61);
series4.set(6.446636814,2877.63);
series4.set(6.334959739,2817.19);
series4.set(6.22,2757.15);
series4.set(6.10,2696.57);
series4.set(5.733552319,2515.440226);
series4.set(5.606696386,2455.409765);
series4.set(5.479072175,2395.397663);
series4.set(5.352603164,2335.233212);
series4.set(4.193900165,1789.978504);
series4.set(4.060604311,1729.807258);
series4.set(3.929124422,1669.649482);
series4.set(3.788668332,1609.300613);
series4.set(2.164222404,1007.059336);
series4.set(1.953838367,946.8072057);
series4.set("0.133522135",-143.4140801);
series4.set(0.066135582,-203.4635544);
series4.set(0.002918748,-263.8554871);
series4.set(-0.066141148,-324.5883882);
series4.set(-0.132174572,-385.96192);
series4.set(-0.921089703,-1172.898889);
series4.set(-0.981256764,-1233.287334);
series4.set(-1.043102173,-1293.57028);
series4.set(-1.106574926,-1353.732824);
series4.set(-1.171650937,-1414.056659);
series4.set(-1.870683363,-1958.84943);
series4.set(-1.994795447,-2019.349098);
series4.set(-2.120681016,-2079.613447);
series4.set(-2.263016586,-2140.611887);
series4.set(-3.903208537,-2926.144838);
series4.set(-3.988282377,-2986.30619);
series4.set(-4.007646719,-3000);
series4.set(-3.980604355,-2926.11742);
series4.set(-3.949245994,-2865.626335);
series4.set(-2.115051141,-1354.208708);
series4.set(-2.002115358,-1294.068933);
series4.set(-1.889545833,-1233.82616);
series4.set(-1.783095962,-1173.504591);
series4.set(-0.09267729,339.9711549);
series4.set(-0.022683854,400.0822902);
series4.set(0.051001135,460.082531);
series4.set(0.130141486,520.4650164);
series4.set(1.946266677,1423.95246);
series4.set(2.127407915,1483.979464);
series4.set(2.30500294,1544.046998);

lineModel1.setStacked(true);
lineModel1.addSeries(series4); 

Axis xAxis=new CategoryAxis("Xdata");

lineModel1.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, xAxis);
Axis yAxis = lineModel1.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
yAxis.setLabel("YData");
```

Now I want the program to connect the dots in order which I gave, which is the order I added them to my series. But I do get them connected in sorted order. I think it is sorted by x-value. 
Is there a way to disable this auto sort. Please suggest.

In bean i set the extender to

```
lineModel1.setExtender("extend");
```

in xhtml:

```
<p:lineChart id="linear" value="#{catalogChartBean.lineModel1}" title="Linear Chart" />
```

in js:

```
function extend(){
   this.cfg=$.jqplot(this.cfg.id, this.cfg.data, {sortData:false});
   this.cfg.redraw(); 
      }
```

i don't think so this function is invoked even, because i wrote a simple window.alert and the extender dint invoke it.

Comment: Having a line chart and not connecting the points in sorted order is very illogical. I think you need a differnt type of chart like a spiderweb/radar chart

Comment: Yeah I agree ! but, this is a line graph with XY scatter plots.. these are reading taken from machinery. So i need to connect these plots in a specific given order(i.e., the order I added them to the series) rather than in some order. Jfreechart has an option to disable sort, how to do it with primefaces ?

Comment: Use string representations of your x-axis values?

Comment: yeah i tried that, dint help :(

Comment: Try a newe version of PF, check the jqplot docs for extender functionality etc

Comment: i have achieved the sortData:false in JQPlot, but i am unable to convey the same in Primefaces. there is no examples also. It would be helpfull if you can provide me the example.

Comment: I don't have it. If I did, I would have given you more hints

Comment: If you post what you tried, maybe I can comment on it

Comment: @Kukeltje : i have updated the post with the code i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and made it work.
I used `<p:lineChart />` and it is not able to invoke the extender. Not sure WHY ?
But i changed it to `<p:chart/>` and it worked.

Also to disable sorting i used this below js via extender.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function extnder() {
        this.cfg.sortData = false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Linechart is the old way of using charts. You have to define the extender ON the linechart tag, not in the model. In the chart tag you define it in the model and not on the tag. But this is weird, if both work it looks like you have two PF versions then

Comment: I am using PF 5.0.4. I even tried having extender on lineChart tag but that dint help then i tried setting it on the bean that dint work either. Changing lineChart to Chart helped.

Comment: using `p:lineChart` and setting it in the bean/model does indeed not work, but the fact that you see a chart by using either the `p:lineChart` OR the `p:chart` is weird and an indication your environment is not 'clean' and not surprising the lineChart is not working correctly anymore. So please do check your environment.